# searching for time specific records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data table that lists weekly timesheet records for applicants.

I need to create a report of applicants who:

Have had a timesheet last week
Who have NOT had a timesheet in the preceding 6 weeks
but HAVE had a timesheet at any time prior to that

Any ideas? not got very far (im new at this)

```
SELECT
    [TimesheetID],
    [PeriodStarting],
    [Sector],
    [ApplicantId]
FROM
    [WebServices].[TimesheetEntity]
where
    [periodstarting] > getdate() - 8 (
        select
            [periodstarting]
        FROM
            [WebServices].[TimesheetEntity]
        where
            [periodstarting] not between (GETDATE() -8)
            AND (GETDATE() -50)
```

Comment: it would be helpfull if you provide a full [mre] with tables data and result not as image

Comment: you need to provide sample data and desired output

Comment: (1) `getdate() - 8` is lazy shorthand that is brittle because it doesn't work with all the date/time types. I would get in the habit of using `DATEADD(DAY, -8, getdate())`. (2) `BETWEEN` is a brittle use case because it only works as expected when everything is `date`. (3) If you're going to use `BETWEEN`, the first argument needs to be the lower value. `getdate()-8` > `getdate()-50` so you need to flip those around. See https://sqlblog.org/dates

Answer (score 0):

if you only need app names , here is one way :

```
select [ApplicantId]    
from [WebServices].[TimesheetEntity]
group by [ApplicantId]
having count(case when periodstarting > dateadd(day, -8, getdate()) then 1 end) > 1  -- check if anyebtry during last 8 days
   and count(case when periodstarting between dateadd(day, -50, getdate()) and dateadd(DAY, -8, getdate()) then 1 end) = 0 -- check no case between last week and last 50 days
   and count(case when periodstarting < dateadd(DAY, -50, getdate()) then 1 end) > 1 -- check if any case up to 50 days ago
```

Comment: thanks for your advice all - as i say i am very new at this so appreciate your feedback

@eshirvana i am getting a syntax error when trying that code unfortunately

Comment: @KimBlackburn actually  fixed the query , bad syntax in case statements, see updated asnwer

Answer (score 0):

EXISTS is very efficient b/c it stops processing once it knows it is true or not.

```
SELECT
    [TimesheetID],
    [PeriodStarting],
    [Sector],
    [ApplicantId]
FROM
    [WebServices].[TimesheetEntity]
where
    exists (select 1    --Have had a timesheet last week
from [WebServices].[TimesheetEntity]
where [periodstarting] > getdate() - 8)

and not exists (    --Who have NOT had a timesheet in the preceding 6 weeks 
        select 1  
        FROM
            [WebServices].[TimesheetEntity]
        where
            [periodstarting] between (GETDATE() -50)
            AND (GETDATE() -8)

and exist ( -- but HAVE had a timesheet at any time prior to 6 weeks
  select 1  
        FROM
            [WebServices].[TimesheetEntity]
        where
            [periodstarting] < (GETDATE() -50)
)
```

Comment: @AaronBertrand Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?

```
SELECT
    [TimesheetID],
    [PeriodStarting],
    [Sector],
    [ApplicantId]
FROM
    [WebServices].[TimesheetEntity]
where
    [periodstarting] between dateadd(week, -1, getdate()) and getdate() # have an timesheet last week 
and (ApplicantId not  in 
      (select ApplicantId 
         from [WebServices].[TimesheetEntity] 
         where periodstarting >= dateadd(week, -7, getdate())
               and periodstarting < dateadd(week, -1, getdate())
    ) # does not have timesheet for last 6 weeks priori to the current one
and 
(ApplicantId in 
      (select ApplicantId 
         from [WebServices].[TimesheetEntity] 
         where  periodstarting < dateadd(week, -7, getdate())
    ) #had timesheet in the past
```

Comment: seem to be getting syntax errors on this solution - just says "near )"

Comment: I can see that I forgot to add `#` in the last line...  anyway, I do not have an access to your database so it's hard to me to confirm that syntax is correct (there is a chance that I messed up with brackets or something like that), but I think you should be able to figure out how to fix such typos

Comment: thanks radek - i;ve managed to get it working - for some reason i need to go back two weeks to get timesheets from last week but it appears to be working now.

Only issue is that it's pulling everyone through twice when they have more than one timesheet since last week - any ideas?

Comment: In the script above as an 'previous week' I used exactly previous 7 days'. So for example Monday last week do not meet that criteria. The question is if that is what you are looking for... 
Only issue is that it's pulling everyone through twice when they have more than one timesheet since last week' - script returns all records which meet the criteria. So if you have two entries from the same week, both will be fine. You can replace 
SELECT
    [TimesheetID],
    [PeriodStarting],
    [Sector],
    [ApplicantId]
FROM

with select distinct  [ApplicantId] from... to get single rows